# Flexslider in a modal window not loading first slide until window resize

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, flexslider

I am using Flexslider in a modal window. When I open the modal window, the Flexslider appears as well as the next/prev navigation but the first slide is not loaded until I re-size the browser window, then it displays as should be.

This problem seems consistent across Firefox 11.0, Chrome 19.0.1084.56 & Opera 12.02.

To illustrate the issue, click the first image [here](http://www.ianbatt.eu/work.html)

I have read that jQuery cannot work with hidden elements, or is this even the issue? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I found a solution to this exact issue. I'm using Foundation and opening a new page with the Reveal modal window with a flexslider in it.

```
(function($) {
            $(window).ready(function(){
                $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                    animation: "slide",
                    start: function(slider){
                        $('body').removeClass('loading');
                    }
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
```